# JavaScript string replace URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on trying to make a changing help link.
The URL of the help manual has a pageid. As you navigate through our application, the link and pageid changes.

An example of the url is: http://www.google.com/custom?pageid=#pageid

Currently I'm using

```
function ReplaceHelpLink(pageId) {
    $(".helpLinkReplace", document).each(function (index, helpLink) {
         helpLink.href = helpLink.href.replace("#pageid", pageId);
    });
 }
```

But this doesn't handle the situation, when the url has changed, for example http://www.google.com/custom?pageid=1

How would you handle this? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: When do you call this function ?

Comment: Went moving between pages in the application

Comment: post the code when you call it please.

Comment: ink.Attributes["OnClick"] = "ReplaceHelpLink(" + Convert.ToInt32(siteMapNode["pageId"]) + ");";

Comment: I don't think setting the onclick event the way you are doing is the correct way.
You would have to do ink.onclick = ReplaceHelpLink(Convert.ToInt32(siteMapNode.pageId));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace something more like this:

```
....replace(/#pageid|\d+/,pageId);
```

This will handle both the case of first replacement, and susequent replacements too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ReplaceHelpLink(pageId) {
    $(".helpLinkReplace", document).each(function (index, helpLink) {
         var link = $(this).attr("href").replace("#pageid", pageId);
         $(this).attr("href",link);
    });
 }
```